# How i can fix my url parameter?

Tags: php, laravel

I trying to get value from "url parameter" with below url.

```
http://dev.xxx.local/th/xxx/zzz?url=https://integ.zzz.com?PlayerName={playerName}&OperatorName={operatorName}&AuthCode={authCode}&GameId=2&GameType=ZZZ
```

My code

```
$url = (string) $request->input('url');

return $url;
```

But url return only

```
https://integ.livepbt.com?PlayerName={playerName}
```

This is what i need.

```
https://integ.zzz.com?PlayerName={playerName}&OperatorName={operatorName}&AuthCode={authCode}&GameId=2&GameType=ZZZ
```

What happen to my code?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking at the query() method instead of input()

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/requests#retrieving-input

You can do

```
$request->query();
```

which will give you everything you are after.

Edit:

You have a problem in your formatting that you would need to fix for this to work properly. Generally a question mark indicates the start of a query string and ampersand would indicate a key=value